# passing multiple id's from one view to another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, html

```
for (i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
   sessionStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(query[i].id));
   alert(sessionStorage.getItem("key"));
}
```

In the above for loop i am putting the id value in the session storage,the problem i am facing is that,If the loop execute multiple times then in the sessionStorage the last value is only storing and loading my last record with that value only.

but i want for each iteration i want to retrieve the id value and with all the values I have to display all records.

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the same key called `key`. You could directly stringify the entire object without writing any loops:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(query));
```

Now on the other page:

```
var query = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('key'));

// directly access an element given its index
alert(query[0].id);

// or loop:
for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
    alert(query[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var z=0;
for (i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
   z=z+1;
   sessionStorage.setItem("key"+(Z), JSON.stringify(query[i].id));
}
sessionStorage.setItem("keyResord", JSON.stringify(z));

for(i=0;i<sessionStorage.getItem("keyResord");i++)
{
    alert(sessionStorage.getItem("key"));
}
```

might be it will work for you, it's working at my end

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler: why not use already built in structures and components?
On the sending page:

```
TempData["<your key>"] = JSON.stringify(query)
```

On the receiving page:

```
var yourVariable = TempData["Key"]
// at this point @yourVariable on receiving page has the same value as stringified query bu JSON

// as Darin mentioned you access elements like this:
alert(@yourVariable[<your index>].id);
```